Adding data if elements from 2 different rows in 2 different CSV files matches using Bash scripting
I am very new to Bash scripting and still at the learning stage. Currently, I am working on CSV files and there has been a requirement that if 2 rows are matched in 2 different CSV files, then the data column should be added.
For example,
csv_file1.csv:
Account,Entity,Data
A1101,E101,1000

csv_file2.csv:
Account,Entity,Data
A1101,E101,2000
A1101,E102,2000

On executing bash script, the expected output should be a new CSV file with rows:
Account,Entity,Data
A1101,E101,3000
A1101,E102,2000

Since, elements in 1st row of "csv_file1" and elements in 1st row of "csv_file2" are matching, data in the "Data" column should append.
The below is the code which I have tried to print the contents of both CSV files. But, I am not able to move forward from here.
#!/bin/bash
#assigns the CSV file to a variable
FILE1="csv_file1.csv"

#reads each line and splits it into three variables

while IFS=, read -r Account Entity Data; do

echo "$Account#""$Entity#""$Data"

done < <(tail -n +2 $FILE1)

#assigns the CSV file to a variable
FILE2="csv_file2.csv"

#reads each line and splits it into three variables

while IFS=, read -r Account Entity Data; do

echo "$Account#""$Entity#""$Data"

done < <(tail -n +2 $FILE2)

It would be great if you guys can help me with your ideas. please let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks a lot in Advance!

Why not use awk?
   -k    --csv    Enable special processing for files with comma separated values (CSV). See Working With Comma Separated Value Files. This option cannot be used with --posix. Attempting to do causes a fatal error. -F fs --field-separator fs

With PHP, I build an array with Account and Entity as Index. When the Array Key does not exist, create, otherwise add the value.

Your bash script lacks the comparison between the two inputs and the sum when rows match.
If you absolutely want to do this with just bash, if your CSV files are as simple as what you show (no quoted fields, no newlines in fields...), if you want to also print lines that are found in only one of the two input files, and if you don't care about the final order, then you can try:
#!/bin/bash

declare -iA a=()
declare -i Data
declare Account Entity

FILE1="csv_file1.csv"
FILE2="csv_file2.csv"

head -n1 "$FILE1"

while IFS=, read -r Account Entity Data; do
  a["$Account,$Entity"]+=Data
done < <(tail -n +2 "$FILE1"; tail -n +2 "$FILE2")

for k in "${!a[@]}"; do
  printf '%s,%d\n' "$k" ${a[$k]}
done

For performance reasons awk would be a better choice than bash. With the same assumtions as for the bash version, you can try the following with any awk:
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
NR == 1 { print; next }
FNR == 1 { next }
{ a[$1 OFS $2] += $3 }
END { for(k in a) print k, a[k] }
' csv_file1.csv csv_file2.csv

We declare the comma as input (FS) and output (OFS) field separators. We print the header line of the first file and skip the header line of the second file.
While parsing the files we store the content in array a with 2 first fields as key and last field as value (e.g., a[A1101,E101] = 1000), adding the third field to the value if the key exists already.
At the end (END) we print the content of array a.
If your CSV format is more complex, with double-quoted fields, possibly containing escaped double-quotes ("") or even newline characters, you could try the --csv option of recent versions of GNU awk:
awk --csv '
function quote(s) {
  if(s ~ /[",\n]/) {
    gsub(/"/, "\"\"", s)
    s = "\"" s "\""
  }
  return s
}

BEGIN { OFS = "," }
NR == 1 { print; next }
FNR == 1 { next }
{ a[$1][$2] += $3 }
END { for(k1 in a) for(k2 in a[k1]) print quote(k1), quote(k2), a[k1][k2] }
' csv_file1.csv csv_file2.csv

Demo:
$ cat csv_file1.csv 
Account,Entity,Data
A1101,E101,1000
A1101,"E101,E102",3000
A1101,"hello, ""world""",1000

$ cat csv_file2.csv 
Account,Entity,Data
A1101,E101,2000
A1101,E102,2000
A1101,"E101,E102",2000
A1101,"hello, ""world""",4000

$ awk --csv -f foo2.awk csv_file*
Account,Entity,Data
A1101,"hello, ""world""",5000
A1101,E101,3000
A1101,E102,2000
A1101,"E101,E102",5000

But then, a real CSV parser would probably be safer.

Hi Renaud, Worked wonderfully. Thanks for the help! Out of curiosity, is it possible to arrange data which is enclosed in double quotes? like for Entity column, if there is data like "E101,E102", awk code is ignoring those double quotes.

It would be possible but there you would be parsing a more complex CSV format. What if you have escaped double quotes in some fields? I don't recommend parsing complex CSV without a dedicated parser. You could try the --csv option of GNU awk but even this has limitations. Or you could try one of the many CSV toolkits (e.g., csvkit).

In case your CSV is more complex than what you show in your question, I edited my answer to show how to use the --csv option of recent versions of GNU awk.

== file: chk.awk ==
@load "filefuncs"
{
  #// input: file=xxx.csv

  #// check if $file defined
  if (file=="") {
    printf ("Please use `-v file=xxx.csv` to define a csv file\n");
    exit 2;
  }

  #// check if inout file exist
  ret=stat(file,fdata)
  if (ret<0) {
    printf ("File '%s' seems not exist !?\n", file);
    exit 3;
  }

  printf ("* NR=%d\n", NR);

  printf ("1st file:'%s'\n", $0);
  #// Read from 2nd file
  ret = getline sec < file
  if (ret)
    printf ("2nd file:'%s'\n", sec);
  else
    printf ("2nd file already EOF\n");
    #//? Terminated ? 
} END {
  #// 1st file END, but how about 2nd?
  if (ret) {
    printf ("2nd left: --\n");
    while (ret) {
      ret = getline sec < file
      if (ret) printf ("2nd: '%s'\n", sec );
    }
  }
}

undre commandline:
$ gawk -k  -v file=2.csv -f chk.awk 1.csv
* NR=1
1st file:'Account,Entity,Data'
2nd file:'Account,Entity,Data'
* NR=2
1st file:'A1101,E101,1000'
2nd file:'A1101,E101,2000'
2nd left: --
2nd: 'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd: 'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd: 'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd: 'A1101,E102,2000'

or
$ gawk -k  -v file=1.csv -f chk.awk 2.csv
* NR=1
1st file:'Account,Entity,Data'
2nd file:'Account,Entity,Data'
* NR=2
1st file:'A1101,E101,2000'
2nd file:'A1101,E101,1000'
* NR=3
1st file:'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd file already EOF
* NR=4
1st file:'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd file already EOF
* NR=5
1st file:'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd file already EOF
* NR=6
1st file:'A1101,E102,2000'
2nd file already EOF

You can compare the different between these 2 files by yourself now
